# How to bind 'og:site_name' to the URI link for Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, uri, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

For the blog on my website I use i-frame button with open graph meta-tags. Everything ok, `og:url` links to my article, but `og:site_name` links directly on my root link website.com, not to the website.com/blog. Is there a way to set it right?

Comment: root?! the `og:site_name` should be your SITE NAME: `A human-readable name for your site, e.g., "IMDb".` !

Comment: yes, it is, but "human-readable name" in my fb's like layout links on my root website, not in to the website.com/blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it always links to the root of your site.

Comment: is there any explanation why?